# Send data to a Text Widget when onPressed is performed

Tags: flutter

I am building my project and I would to know how to send the data to a new TextWidget in flutter
here in the code how you can see I have print('confirm $date');
this confirmation date has to be printed ina Text widget in flutter into a alertdialog.
here is the code for the confirmation:

```
FlatButton(
              color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
              onPressed: () {
                DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                    showTitleActions: true,
                    minTime: DateTime(1, 1, 2020),
                    maxTime: DateTime(2020, 12, 1),
                    theme: DatePickerTheme(
                        headerColor: Color(0xfffeaf0d),
                        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                        itemStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18),
                        doneStyle:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
                    onChanged: (date) {
                      print('change $date in time zone ' +
                          date.timeZoneOffset.inHours.toString());
                    }, onConfirm: (date) {
                      print('confirm $date');
                    }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.it);
              },
```

as you can see in the lasts line of code there is a onPressed function that prints confirm $date in the console.
I want to print the output into a text widget in flutter.
How I can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable to receive the `date` in `onConfirm` and set the variable as the `Text` content.

```
String confirmDate = ''; 


onConfirm: (date) {
   setState(() {
      confirmDate = date.toString();
   });
}
```

OR

```
onChange: (date) {
   setState(() {
      confirmDate = date.toString();
   });
}
...

Text(confirmDate);
```

Comment: I got an exception: a non null string must be provided to a Text widget.

Comment: But you used my answer or the answer that you accepted?

Comment: I used your answer

Comment: Initialize the confirmDate with `String confirmDate = ''`. If not work move the setState from onConfirm to onChange.

Comment: I edited my answer. if works you must accept my answer as the valid answer.

Comment: Thanks String confirmDate = ''; 
solved the things!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the StateFul Widget from Flutter. First declare your state variable and Once the date is changed, set it in the state variable like:

```
onConfirm: (date) => {
  this.setState(() {
    selectedDate: date
  })
}
```

Then you can use that state variable anywhere in the whole widget. To simply print it inside a Text, use:

```
Text(selectedDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The full code I got " A non null string must be provided to a text widget as exception

```
class PaymentPop extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _PaymentPopState createState() => _PaymentPopState();
}

class _PaymentPopState extends State<PaymentPop> {
  String confirmDate;

  TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/images/pickupman.png',
              width: 160,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Text('Spedizione pagata con successo'),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
              onPressed: () {
                DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                    showTitleActions: true,
                    minTime: DateTime(2020, 1, 1),
                    maxTime: DateTime(2021, 12, 1),
                    theme: DatePickerTheme(
                        headerColor: Color(0xfffeaf0d),
                        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                        itemStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18),
                        cancelStyle:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                        doneStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16)), onChanged: (date) {
                  print('change $date in time zone ' +
                      date.timeZoneOffset.inHours.toString());
                }, onConfirm: (date) {
                  setState(() {
                    confirmDate = date.toString();
                  });
                }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.it);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Prenota il ritiro',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            Text(confirmDate),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```